# Email Verification in Django when a new user signs up

Tags: django, django-views, email-validation, django-users, django-email

I am creating a user registration page for my website. I want to send an email verification mail to the mail the user inputs while registering. I tried many solutions but nothing seems to work for me.
My code:

## views.py

```
def registerPage(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)
            return redirect('login')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'Home/register.html', context)

def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')
            return redirect('login')
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'Home/login.html', context)
```

## forms.py

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
```

Comment: What kind of help you need ? General idea of what to do ? Technical elements ?

Comment: The technical solution will be great. I tried a few solutions none worked. So a complete solution will be cherished.